# Adding two products to cart with one click on the "Add to cart" button. Open Cart 1.5.5.1

Tags: addition, opencart, cart

I have created ***configurator.tpl*** file (duplicate of ***product.tpl*** + some editing) in ***catalog/view/theme/theme-name/template/product/configurator.tpl*** in order to have 2 products at the same time on the product page. Also, I have created the controller file ***catalog/controller/product/configurator.php*** (duplicate of ***product.php*** + some editing). Everything it's OK. You can check [here](http://www.bekinilab.ro/opncrt/index.php?route=product/configurator&path=59&product_id=50).

Now, I'm trying to add these 2 products to cart, clicking once the "Add to cart" button. Always these two products will be the same two (product_id=50 and product_id=51).
Do I have to modify "add to cart function", or maybe to call the function twice, once for each product_id? Any approach will be OK.

I've found some valuable info [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=91440) but I can't imagine the solution. Please help!

Open Cart 1.5.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
  $('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.product-info.first input[type=\'text\'], .product-info.first input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info.first input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info.first input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info.first select, .product-info.first textarea'),
```

to

```
addtocart2(pid) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#product-'+pid+' .product-info.first input[type=\'text\'], #product-'+pid+' .product-info.first input[type=\'hidden\'],#product-'+pid+'  .product-info.first input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product-'+pid+' .product-info.first input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product-'+pid+' .product-info.first select,#product-'+pid+'  .product-info.first textarea'),
```

And replace

```
 <input type="button" value="Adauga in cos" id="button-cart" class="button" />
```

to

```
 <input type="button" value="Adauga in cos" onclick="addtocart2(<?=$product_id ?>)" class="button" />
```

and in the end add html id to priduct-info div

```
<div class="product-info first">
```

replace to

```
<div class="product-info first" id="product-<?=$product_id?>">
```

I do not know how you do output,so $product_id may be changed to $product['product_id'] or $product2_id;

Comment: I've done something quite similar:  1) Doubled the **$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {** function body.  2) Replace in data: $('.product-info.second...  3) Change <div class="product-info"> to <div class="product-info first"> and <div class="product-info second">  4) change <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product_id_2; ?>" />  I'll post my similar solution as separate answer

Answer (score 0):

All the changes are for ***configurator.tpl***
Replace ***$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {***
 with

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('.product-info.first input[type=\'text\'], .product-info.first input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info.first input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info.first input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info.first select, .product-info.first textarea'),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();
        if (json['error']) {
            if (json['error']['option']) {
                for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                    $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                }
            }
        } 

        if (json['success']) {
            $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');
            $('.success').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
        }   
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('.product-info.second input[type=\'text\'], .product-info.second input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info.second input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info.second input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info.second select, .product-info.second textarea'),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();
        if (json['error']) {
            if (json['error']['option']) {
                for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                    $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                }
            }
        } 

        if (json['success']) {
            $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');
            $('.success').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        }   
    }
});
});
```

Replace `<div class="product-info">` with
`<div class="product-info first">` (for product 1) and with
`<div class="product-info second">` (for product 2)

Replace just for the second product
`<input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product; ?>" />` with
`<input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product_id_2; ?>" />`

That's all.